# Unable to open the file .mdf/.ldf. Operating system error 5: 5"(Access is denied.)" - Trying to replace .mdf/.ldf file with new one

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, file-permissions

I have the ability to move `.mdf`/`.ldf` files at will from the default `\DATA` folder location. I can set the database online and offline whenever I move these files manually.

We get a new set of `.mdf`/`.ldf` file every month to replace the one that we have. I am trying to automate this process with SSIS. I have managed to create a package that will handle replacing the old `.mdf`/`.ldf` files with the new ones.

**BUT!**

The SQL task to turn on the database with the new `.mdf`/`.ldf` files does not run.

I get this error:

> Error: 0xC002F210 at Take Sandbox Online, Execute SQL Task: Executing the query "ALTER DATABASE Sandbox SET ONLINE" failed with the following error: "Unable to open the physical file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SERVER\MSSQL\DATA\SANDBOX.mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".
>
> Unable to open the physical file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SERVER\MSSQL\DATA\SANDBOX_LOG.ldf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".

I am able to do this process manually, but for some reason SSIS is not able to turn the database back on with a SQL Task. I clearly have permissions to perform this task, but I am ignorant of how running through SSIS would be an issue.

Please help!

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server uses a service account, usually called `NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER`, which needs to have permissions on the mdf/ldf files.

Right click the files, click properties / security /edit / add, and add the account to permissions.

Comment: Can you help me understand how these tools navigate what account to use? I am using my local account to run the SSIS package, why is the 'NT Service' account required?

Comment: To bring the DB online, SSIS calls through to SQL Server and asks it to do so. SSIS does not open the DB files, SQL Server does, and it needs the right account permissions. SQL Server runs as a Windows Service.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance, this is very interesting. The account I am using also has credentials to run on SQL Server, is it possible to direct SQL Server to use a different account of my choosing for this instance?

Comment: You cannot chnage it just for one operation otherwise the DB won't come back online next time. Best not to change permanently for security. The service account is there for a reason, it has a long and unchanging password, and limited permissions. What you can do is give it inheritable permissions to the whole folder you are placing these DBs in, then it will get automatic permission to those files

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This was great for helping me discuss how things need to be configured with our IT department. Your solution did solve the problem, but I also needed the context you provided as well. It is much appreciated!